# Laravel Order By Specific String

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by

I have data on my **PostgreSQL** like this :

**background**

```
id | Size
1  | small
2  | medium
3  | large
```

**art**

```
id | name       | background_id
1  | Shine      | 1
2  | Sun        | 3
3  | Mountain   | 3
```

I want to get art data orderBy background by it's value from small (small, medium, large) with laravel eloquent

```
Art::with( [ 'background' => function( $background ) {
    $background->oderBy( DB::raw( "what is this?" ) );
} ] )->get();
```

How to fix it?

```
FIELD(type, 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL')
```

is not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `CASE WHEN` expression along with `orderByRaw():`

```
$queryOrder = "CASE WHEN Size = 'small' THEN 1 ";
$queryOrder .= "WHEN Size = 'medium' THEN 2 ";
$queryOrder .= "ELSE 3 END";
Art::with('background')
->orderByRaw($queryOrder);
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add an `order` field to the background table so ordening can be changed when a new field is added without having to change code. Then, you can use the following query:

```
Art::with('background')
->orderBy('background.order')
->get();
```

Comment: It's show error SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Comment: Have you set the `$table` property in your `Art` model?